# Oscommerce PayPal IPN still Status pending

Tags: paypal, oscommerce

I'm working with oscommerce and i have problem with Paypal ipn When someone makes a payment, even though the money is coming through OK, on the backend of the website it is saying it is unverified

something like that

: PayPal IPN Verified [Completed (Unverified; $99.90).

I get the email "Notification of payment received" so why is it still pending?

any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Unverified" there may mean the buyer has not finished the Paypal account/address verification process.

This information is included in the variable `payer_status`:

> Possible Values
>   `verified` Customer has a Verified PayPal account.
>   `unverified` Customer has an Unverified PayPal account.

Details: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf
page 52